# Find and replace a line that contains a dynamic path using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Using some type of JavaScript I need to replace what will be a dynamic file path in code line that could look like this:

```
<script src="//widgets.com/scripts/complete-test.js?border=false&amp;header=false&amp;more=false"></script><div style="display: none;" class="widgets-html">
```

or it could look this:

```
<script src="//widgets.com/anotherdirectory/some-other-file.js?active=yes"></script><div style="display: none;" class="widgets-html">
```

so basically the line will take some form like this (note the */*):

```
<script src="//widgets.com/*/*"></script><div style="display: none;" class="widgets-html">
```

and replace the whole line with this:

```
<div class="widgets-html">
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Removing a script from DOM after it has already ran will make no difference (except that it won't be showing in the DOM anymore, of course).

Comment: It's a task I've been assigned to do, and not sure precisely how to go about solving it. I haven't seen the end code that it is working with yet. Right now I am just following a request.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to modify some source code then you can easily do something like the following:

`str.replace(/<script src="\/\/widgets.com\/.+?\/.+?"><\/script><div style="display: none;" class="widgets-html">/, '<div class="widgets-html">');`

But if you need to unload a script from a page that's already loaded it is impossible, although there are workarounds such as manually emptying your JS object or whatever is returned or set by that particular script. You can also use JS and/or jQuery to toggle the display of the `.widgets-html` `div`.